# Sliding power switch for the PCB

Tags: pcb, switches

I need a simple sliding switch for power. However, the search I have done so far shows switches that have more than 2 positions (e.g ON-OFF-ON) and a whole lot of contacts on the PCB. It does not make sense. I think that a power switch needs to have 2 positions ON-OFF and thus just two pins to connect to the PCB.

Lets take and example:

[image]

Questions:

1. This switch has 8 contacts. The schematic somehow indicates that 3-4 and 7-8 are connected? Maybe not. I don't know what the arrow between 3-4 and 7-8 represents.
2. How is it possible that there are three positions and all of them are ON? This makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Double pole triple throw switch - DP3T is an abbreviation for that.

The thick black things represent moving contacts, while the arrows pointing up or down to them represent fixed contacts.  Terminals 3 and 7 each have two contacts that can touch the moving contacts.

The switch schematic is drawn with the switch in the full right position, connecting terminal 3 to 4 and 7 to 8.  In the middle position terminal 3 is connected to 2, and 7 to 6.  In the Left position, 3 is connected to 1 and 7 is connected to 5.

Put another way, terminal 3 can be connected to 1, 2, or 4, and 7 can be connected to 5, 6, or 8 when the handle is in the Left, Center or Right position.

This switch could be used to select one of three stereo audio sources (or many similar applications - that's just the first application that came to my mind.)

Comment: The simplest switches I have found so far are still having 3 contacts. Are there no switches that have only 2 contacts so we can do ON-OFF using them? Maybe they have some special name?

Comment: You are looking for a SPST (single pole single throw) switch.  You could use a SPDT (single pole double throw) and ignore the third terminal, or use a DPDT and either ignore one pole, or connect the two poles in parallel.

Comment: @PeterBennett Or connect the two poles in series. That's probably preferable for switching power, as it gives you effectively a double-break switch.

Comment: OK so that still means 3 positions right? The middle one will be OFF and the side one will be ON or the other way around.

Comment: A double-throw switch will normally only have two positions.  There are double-throw switches that have three handle positions, with the center position being Off.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the three positions shown:

[image]

The moving blocks shown schematically the way the slide switch is actually built inside.

So pin 3 is the common and it gets connected to 4, 2, or 1 depending on the position. And similarly with 7 on the second set of contacts.

---

There are plenty of two-position (and more than three position) slide switches.

Comment: On the seller websites I come across this terminology for the "switch operation": [1] (On)-Off-(On) ; [2] On-Off-(On) ; [3] On-Off-On . What is the difference between these three? I don't understand what something being in bracket means.

Comment: In this context, it indicates that the operation is momentary. That's typically a toggle switch or similar that returns to the center position when you take your hand off of it.

Comment: You mean that it has some sort of spring that prevents it from staying in a particular position for long so when the hand is lifted, it returns to a different state? This means that I need to avoid any switch that shows () in the "switch operation" chart?

Comment: Yes, a spring return.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another depiction of the contacts of either pole of a DP3T (double-pole triple-throw) switch.

[image]

'1', '2', & '3' are the fixed contacts with 'C' being the common.

The three positions of the moving contact are as shown.

Comment: OK, now I finally understand what that diagram actually meant.